# stop gitlab-runner from removing directories

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have this folder `src/public/uploads` which contains all the images uploaded by the users of my application. Of course that images are not uploaded to the repository.

The issue is that when I start the pipeline, `gitlab-runner` automatically remove this folder from the server. That is weird 'cause I've excluded this directory using:

```
git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch src/public/uploads
```

also, inside that folder I have a `.gitkeep` file. This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: docker/compose:1.28.6

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: -x -f -e src/public/uploads/**

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - production
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - cp ~/razor/docker/.env .
    - cp ~/razor/app/.env ./src
    - cp ~/razor/app/www.conf ./docker/php-fpm/config
    - cp ~/razor/app/authsources.php ./src/app/Config/Simplesaml/config
    - cp ~/razor/app/config.php ./src/app/Config/Simplesaml/config
    - docker-compose up --build -d
```

I have added this: `GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: -x -f -e src/public/uploads/**`

for prevent removal, but same issue.

This is the `.gitignore`:

```
.env
src/app/Config/Simplesaml/config/authsources.php
src/app/Config/Simplesaml/config/config.php
src/public/uploads
```

Comment: what does your `.gitignore` look like? running `git clean` with the `x` flag looks at this particular file.

Comment: @kenmistry check my update please

Comment: Am i right to assume that you are looking to retain only the folder after running the pipeline?

Comment: @kenmistry yes, I just want to keep the `uploads` directory

Comment: `remove this folder from the server.` How are you checking this? `I've excluded this directory using:` How have you "used" it? From where? How would you expect to access the `src/public/uploads/` folder? Are you using docker executor in gitlab-runner? Is the directory `src/public/uploads/` on the server (why the path is not absolute), or is it a relative path inside current directory inside some registered gitlab-runner executor? If the latter, what is it configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using this configuration:

```
image: docker/compose:1.28.6

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: none

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - production
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - cp ~/razor/docker/.env .
    - cp ~/razor/app/.env ./src
    - cp ~/razor/app/www.conf ./docker/php-fpm/config
    - cp ~/razor/app/authsources.php ./src/app/Config/Simplesaml/config
    - cp ~/razor/app/config.php ./src/app/Config/Simplesaml/config
    - docker-compose up --build -d
```

Essentially I have set the option `GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS` to `none`, it simply disable the cleaning on remote, so every untracked files still exists after the end of the pipeline jobs.